# Determine $s_{10}$ for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the convergent series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

To determine $s_{10}$ which is the sum of the first ten terms, the easiest way of course is to add them up.
However is there another way to figure out $s_{10}$?

Comment: What is $s_{10}$?

Comment: The sum of the first ten terms

Comment: Is $s_{10}$ the partial sum of the series?

Comment: Yes, it is understood that $S10$ means you are adding up the first 10 terms of the given series. There is a quick way with the TI83/84 how to do that...

Comment: If you can come up with a clever way to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-(xy)^{10}}{1-xy} dx dy$ that will work.

Comment: $10$ terms are actually not too much.  Of course, you still can make use the [**Euler-Maclaurin summation formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Comment: It can be shown that as $n \rightarrow \infty$.. $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j^2}\right] \rightarrow \psi ^{(1)}(1)-\psi ^{(1)}(n)$$

Comment: ${10^{-2+1} \over -2 + 1} + \zeta\left(2\right) = {\pi^{2} \over 6} - {1 \over 10} \approx 1.5450$ with relative error of $0.31$ %.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form for this sum...

Comment: As an approximation... $$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j^2} \approx \psi ^{(1)}(1)-\psi ^{(1)}(n)$$

Comment: I'm sure there is a Fourier analysis approximant to this sum (of some reasonably simple function), but I don't remember exactly what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creative telescoping
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{n\geq m}\frac{1}{n^2}&=&\sum_{n\geq m}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq m}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)\\&+&\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n\geq m}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}\right)-\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n\geq m}\frac{1}{n^3(n+1)^3}\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*} $$
hence by recalling that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and plugging in $m=11$ in $(1)$ we get:

$$ H_{10}^{(2)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{2\cdot 11^2}-\frac{1}{6\cdot 11^3}+\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n\geq 11}\frac{1}{n^3(n+1)^3}\tag{2} $$
hence $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{2\cdot 11^2}-\frac{1}{6\cdot 11^3}$ is an approximation of $H_{10}^{(2)}$ with an error $\leq 10^{-6}$.
By Wolstenholme's theorem we know that $11$ is a divisor of the numerator of $H_{10}^{(2)}$ and the denominator of $H_{10}^{(2)}$ is clearly a divisor of $2^6\cdot 3^4\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^2$. These facts allow to turn the previous approximation into an exact evaluation:
$$ H_{10}^{(2)}=\frac{1968329}{1270080}\tag{3}$$
but I wonder why a reasonable person should follow this approach, instead of just adding ten terms of the form $\frac{1}{n^2}$.